# Easier way of getting keyboard input in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pygame, keyboard-events

Is there an easier way to get keyboard input in Pygame than specifying each individual key? For instance,

```
if event.key == pygame.K_a:
    command = command + "a"
elif event.key == pygame.K_b:
    command = command + "b"
elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
    command = command + "c"
```

Is there some way to use a function to do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an entirely different action is necessary for each key, then there isn't really a better way. If multiple keys result in similar actions, where say a single function `f` could take the key as an argument, you could use an `in` expression like so:

```
if event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_b, pygame.K_c):
    f(event.key)
```

An `in` expression evaluates to `True` if what's on the left side is contained within what's on the right side. So, with that code if the key pressed is 'a', 'b', or 'c,' the function `f` will be called with the key as an argument.

As a practical example, say you want either the 'Esc' or 'q' key to quit the program. You could accomplish that this way:

```
if event.key in (pygame.K_ESCAPE, pygame.K_q):
    pygame.quit()
```

The above code is effectively the same as:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
    pygame.quit()
elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
    pygame.quit()
```

### Edit

From a comment, `command` is a string that is concatenated to. If say you wanted to add any key a-z that was pressed to `command`, you could do this:

```
if event.key in range(pygame.K_a, pygame.K_z + 1):
    command += event.unicode
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I could make `f()` print out the ascii value of the key? simply using `print()` prints out the decimal form.

Comment: I believe `print(event.unicode)` would do it, but it looks like that's only available on `KEYDOWN` events, as seen [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) (see the yellow box a little ways down the page), so make sure you're checking for those rather than `KEYUP` events.

Comment: I'm creating an application where the user types into a text box and presses enter. the text in the box is assigned to the variable `command`. I then call `os.system(command)`. Sort of like the run-dialog in GNOME.

Comment: the code
`if event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_b, pygame.K_c):
    print(event.unicode)`
Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a little more information in an edit. Good luck!

Comment: What does the `+1` do?

Comment: The upper bound on `range` is exclusive, so without the `+ 1` a 'z' key would not be detected. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) for `range` for more info.